# How to make a virtual environment my default environment so I don't have to activate it everytime?

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

I created a virtual environment with virtualenv on a windows. I've only been using one virtual env and I want to make it default so I don't have to activate it everytime.
Is there a command for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `PATH` so that every time you run `python` or `pip` they are ran from the virtualenv:

```
setx PATH C:\path\to\virtualenv\Scripts;%PATH%
```

Or with the GUI — Control Panel | System | Environment | System/User Variables, and prepend `C:\path\to\virtualenv\Scripts`.

That should be enough.

Comment: I tried using that command and it gave me an error "Invalid syntax. Default option not allowed more than '2' time(s)". Though I get the idea of changing the the PATH so I changed it to my virtualenv Scripts directory and it's working now. I'll just learn more about this setx command. Thank you @phd.